# How could I convert record type to jsonb or use some opertors such as <@ bewteen jsonb and record in postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm using postgresql 10.6 and meet some problems. I tried to use <@ in pg but it reminds me "operator does not exist: jsonb <@ record".

I use jsonb_to_set convert jsonb to record but record does not support <@.

owner_org js jsonb Type, like [1, 2, 3]

```
SELECT
    org."name" AS NAME,
    COUNT ( * ) AS num 
FROM
    project
    LEFT JOIN "user" ON "user"."id" = (
    SELECT
    to_number( OPERATOR ->> 'id', '99999999' ))
    LEFT JOIN org ON (
    SELECT
    to_number( "user".org_id ->> 0, '99999999' )) = org."id" 
WHERE
    OPERATOR ->> 'id' <> '0' 
    AND project.deleted_at IS NULL 
    AND project.created_at >= '2018-01-20 14:00:00' 
    AND project.created_at <= '2018-09-29 17:00:00' 
    AND project.deleted_at IS NULL 
    AND owner_org::jsonb  <@ (
        '16',
        '20',
        '22',
        '23',
        '24',
        '25',
        '26',
        '27',
        '28',
        '29',
        '30',
        '31',
        '32',
        '33' 
    ) 
GROUP BY
    org."name"
```

I expect the outpou of  "Org_A" 1   but the actual output is

```
LINE 18:  AND jsonb_to_record(owner_org)  <@ (
                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: What do the values in `owner_org` look like, and what is the meaning of that comparison?

Comment: Sorry I forget that,  It's jsonb type, like [1, 2, 3 ]

Comment: And the operator is supposed to mean "is contained in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`('16', '20', ...)` is a row literal in PostgreSQL but the [`<@` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) ("contains") wants `jsonb` on both sides. You should have better luck if you use a JSON array on the right side:

```
owner_org::jsonb <@ '["16","20","22", ...]'::jsonb
```